# Synonyms for qualitative vs. quantitative

Tags: synonyms

I would like to describe a business process that can either undergo a qualitative or a quantitative change and seek a better wording to contrast the two terms. Specifically, I am describing an ecological improvement in product packaging when one can either physically reduce packaging material (quantitative) or change the quality of packaging material (qualitative).

Which set of two terms can successfully replace the **quantitative vs. qualitative** meaning in this context?

EDIT:
This is the actual piece of my essay that uses these terms, which I felt was not as precise as it could potentially be:

> There are two major ways, quantitative and qualitative, to make
>   product packaging more environmentally friendly. With the quantitative
>   improvement, product packaging undergoes a physical reduction of
>   material use, whereas with the qualitative improvement, only the
>   nature of packaging material is changed.

Comment: I at first thought of contrasting the words "physical" and "aesthetic", but after some thought realized that these two words are too vague and can easily describe the both processes.

Comment: Can you not just say "amount of packaging" vs "type of packaging"?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _why_ you would want to replace a couple of very well-understood words, and do so in what I understand to be a formal context? Especially in a formal context, I would expect your audience to know and understand the two words well, probably better and more readily than a set of custom words to describe the same concepts.

Comment: If your goal is to make the whole concept easier to understand, you could simply try to phrase it as a choice between _less packaging_ or _better packaging_. That would effectively indicate the _direction_ of the quantative resp. qualitative change.

Comment: *Quantitative* usually connotes *more* of something, and *qualitative* connotes greater expense.  To avoid such connotations, be less abstract. i.e.:"reducing non-recyclable packaging" vs. "using 100% recyclable packaging".  Or if the packaging materials are  known:  "using less non-recyclable Styrofoam" vs. "using only PETE and cardboard."

Comment: Reduced packaging doesn't imply "worse packaging". It can be as good, just different.

Comment: @agc - thank you, i was hoping for a single-worded term. Your suggestion is good but it is too lengthy.

Comment: @oerkelens I feel that for the purpose of my essay, I could make the distinction more specific using different, more packaging-related terms (if such exist at all). I felt that the original terms are too vague. I might be wrong.

Comment: I seems like you are actually talking about the efficiency of using packaging material (i.e. same material type used more efficiently means less material) and the ecological impact of the material (i.e. same amount/mass of material but the waste is environmentally friendlier). Without greater context I am not sure if quantitative and qualitative are even good terms at all.

Comment: I think that the use of both terms is incorrect. Unless they have a specific meaning in the context of packaging or something, I can hardly imagine anyone to understand that qualitative means changes to the quality of the material. IMO, if you remove the two terms from your sentence it will be much better in...qualitative terms

Comment: @JohnKouraklis and Helmar, removing the terms sounded like an option for me. Is there a way I could still "nickname" the two to make a distinction?

Comment: Perhaps: ...two major ways, one that considers the physical characteristics of packaging and one that considers the quality of the material...

Comment: You may need to include a third category. Why? Because one way to reduce the amount of non-recyclable material in packaging is to take away a non-recyclable component and replace it with perhaps a smaller amount of recyclable material. If, e.g., you replace the non-recyclable plastic with a smaller amount of recyclable plastic (say, a number one plastic for a number six plastic), you are accomplishing BOTH quantitative and qualitative improvements. You could also use MORE recyclable material than the original amount of non-recyclable, but at least "more is less [polluting]."

Comment: @rhetorician, thanks - I consider this option later in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***lighter*** vs ***gentler***.

Relevant definitions from MW dictionary:

> [**light**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/light): having little weight; having relatively little weight in
>   proportion to bulk; not abundant;  less in amount or force than usual
>
> [**gentle**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gentle): not strong or harsh in effect or quality

Also, ***lesser*** should work in place of ***lighter***.

> [**lesser**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lesser): of smaller size